# How to position highcharts tooltip above chart with outside:true

Tags: highcharts

I have a system with lots of highcharts which can be positioned basically anywhere on the page.
Some are very small (e.g. 50px x 50px).
I see we can set [tooltip.outside : true](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.outside)

```
tooltip: {
    outside: true
}
```

This stops the tooltip taking over the whole chart container by breaking it out of the chart and into the window.
However this can cause overflow issues with the window when you're near the edge of the page and I personally prefer a static tooltip.

I'd like to always fix the tooltip to float above the chart, top left with a bit of padding, which for my application will almost always be visible and will avoid overflow issues, e.g.;

[image: Top left]

I've looked into setting a [custom positioner](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner), however, as the "outside" tooltip is now part of the window and not relative to the chart, the positioner sets a fixed position, which isn't suitable for my application.
I'd like the tooltip to always be above the chart regardless of mouse or scroll positions.

Of course I could add a custom element and position it above the chart myself, then applying the tooltip to that, but we have a lot of charts and this seems cumbersome.

[Tooltip outside Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattscotty/gzp8vt9f/1/)

Suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of poking around in the highstock Tooltip.prototype.getPosition code, it turns out what I needed was this.point.chart.**pointer.getChartPosition()**;

```
        tooltip: {
            distance: 40,
            outside: true,
            positioner: function () {
                var point = this;
                var chart = point.chart;
                var chartPosition = chart.pointer.getChartPosition();
                var distance = point.distance;

                //Position relative to renderTo container
                return {
                    x: chartPosition.left - distance,
                    y: chartPosition.top - distance - (point.options.useHTML == true ? point.label.div.offsetHeight : point.label.height)
                }

                //Alternatively - Position relative to chart plot (ignoring legend)
                var containerScaling = chart.containerScaling;
                var scaleX = function (val) {
                    return (containerScaling ? val * containerScaling.scaleX : val);
                };
                var scaleY = function (val) {
                    return (containerScaling ? val * containerScaling.scaleY : val);
                };

                return {
                    x: chartPosition.left - distance + scaleX(chart.plotLeft),
                    y: chartPosition.top - distance + scaleY(chart.plotTop) - point.label.height
                }
            },
        },
```

[See working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattscotty/vbc5mps3/).

I find it odd that this method is attached to pointer, but it's what I was after.

One thing to note, in the fiddle I use point.label.height, if useHTML:true; use point.label.div.height.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `positioner` callback without setting the 'outside' option? It will set the wanted position inside the chart area.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gabjwd2e/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The problem is when the charts are very small (i.e. smaller than the tooltip itself), which is why I turned to the "outside" option. But positioning the tooltip in a consistent position, while outside of the chart, is the problem.

Comment: So, have you considered to define the tooltip as an outstanding HTML element and positioning this element wherever you want? You can achieve it by setting the `useHTML` to true: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.useHTML

Comment: Yes I appreciate we can do this, but we've a lot of charts with a lot of different scenarios (style / layout). It feels a little hacky and cumbersome to do this, which is why I was hoping there was a better solution, preferably using positioner or another combination of chart settings.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this case on some online editor that I could work on? Without it, I can only try to guess the solution...

Comment: Sure, see this fiddle, it essentially shows the problem where the positioner puts it top left of the container, rather than the chart container; https://jsfiddle.net/mattscotty/4fchgpdr/2/

Comment: @MattScott, try this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2co0syew/

Comment: Hi, no sorry that doesn't do the trick. I should have mentioned that the charts may also be in a scrollable div (which is why the positioning needs to be relative to the chart itself).
Really I need an option to set whether the "outside" tooltip container is appended after  the chart or the window I suppose.
Leaving the positioner empty gets quite close to what I'm after as the tooltip is always positioned correctly relative to the chart... I just need it to stay still near the chart rather than follow the mouse.

Comment: @MattScott I see, try this config instead: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tuno0w38/

Comment: Hi, thanks for that effort, after looking at it, I've realised the container is in an absolutely positioned parent container (see e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/mattscotty/q8ouxgfk/).
As the tooltip is assigned to the window rather than after the chart (and in the same container), the offset postions are completley wrong for this purpose.
Looking at it, its looking like its not possible without a hacked div for each chart as you can't set where the tooltip is appended to (window or chart renderTo).

Comment: @MattScott In this case you need to add these parent container properties also to the tooltip coordinates: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/29cv783n/

Comment: Thanks for your help.
The problem is the charts can be a few levels deep but this varies.
I've managed to get a version working using your logic, but its still quite hacky as I have to determine the specific containers within my application that offset the chart.
The default "outside" positioner seems to be what I want, but it just needs to position based on the chart rather than the cursor.
Looking at Tooltip.prototype.getPosition in Highstock.js code, all the pieces are there, but it would mean overriding the code itself.
followPointer:false doesn't help either.

Comment: @MattScott it seems that your case is a really specific one. As I understand you have found some hacky solution. If you want to override the `getPosition` you can use the wrap feature - https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: I dont think its that specific as the use cases I describe have been taken into account in the core Highstock code, its just I want the position relative to the chart rather than the cursor. Many thanks for all your help though, much appreciated, I'll take a look into the wrap feature. Matt